# How to remove unwanted white space from my print page

Tags: html, css

How to remove unwanted white space from my printed output, while printing my `div`. I have to print content of DIV like `POS` receipt but it getting extra white space at top and bottom, I just want print only `div` content.

[This image with marked unwanted space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prrYh.jpg)

[This is image of current printing receipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKlUN.jpg)

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 100mm 150mm;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <center>
    <div>Job Sheet</div>
    <h2>
      <b>My Company Name</b>
      <br/>

      <small>My Address here</small><br/>
      <small>1234567890, 1234567890</small><br/>
    </h2>
    <hr/>

    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td class="printHeading"><b>Date: </b></td>
        <td id="date1" class="printHeading">000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="printHeading"><b>Job No: </b></td>
        <td id="caseid1" class="printHeading">fgnfg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="printHeading"><b>Name: </b></td>
        <td id="name1" class="printHeading">fgnfgn</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="printHeading"><b>Address: </b></td>
        <td id="address1" class="printHeading">fgnfg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="printHeading"><b>Mobile: </b></td>
        <td id="mobile1" class="printHeading">fgnfg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="printHeading"><b>Brand: </b></td>
        <td id="brand1" class="printHeading">fgnfgn</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="printHeading"><b>Model: </b></td>
        <td id="model1" class="printHeading">fgsfg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="printHeading"><b>IMEI Number: </b></td>
        <td id="imei_number1" class="printHeading">75375732</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="printHeading"><b>Problem: </b></td>
        <td id="problem1" class="printHeading">fgjdfgdfg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="printHeading"><b>Amount: </b></td>
        <td id="totalAmount1" class="printHeading">535</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="printHeading"><b>Assessories: </b></td>
        <td id="assessories1" class="printHeading">dfgdg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <hr/>
    <div>T & C : NO Responsibility of data lost during service all Subject To Gwalior jurisdiction </div>
  </center>
  <!-- <div>Exe Name</div> -->
  <div>

    <h5 class="pull-right">Customer's Signature</h5>
  </div>

</div>

This is my java script function

function printdiv(printpage)
{
var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
var footstr = "</body>";
var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr+footstr;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
return false;
}
```

Comment: Hello please check the screen shot and let me know where you don't want space and mark in the screen shot. https://prnt.sc/hhmme1

Comment: Can you add the outer element of this div?

Comment: hello @kumavat5611 I have added screenshot with marked unwanted white spaces  "This image with marked unwanted space"

Comment: Hello @romil please check your answer below : if any issues please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be multiple causes for this issue.
On the one hand there could be an issue with the printer driver. Probably the page is set to a specific height in the driver and your content just get centered on the page, maybe you have set margins to 3cm or so, which would make sense on A4-paper but non on receipts.

Furthermore your CSS-File looks a bit short. I would recommend *always* to put in something like

```
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

at the front of your CSS file and then set all margins manually to avoid some strange things browsers and printer drivers might do...

Comment: It is not working, after adding this it look like this, this is screenshot. http://prateekmobile.justevent.in/printpage.jpg

Comment: As I said, it looks like an issue in your print settings. Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: We are using Windows, please suggest us setting that we have to change.

Comment: I put you a new answer above/below/whereever it shows up... I actually don't have a Windows Mashine here but removing the Browser-header and -footer (this which prints the link, and "page X of Y", and so on...) in your print settings should solve your problems. How to do this in your browser should be easy to google...

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please use below link code : 
[https://plnkr.co/edit/sQiJfyaZYbFtChXWAjRn?p=preview][1]

or Change only this :

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 10mm 20mm;
  }
}
```

Comment: not working, I am printing with this function, function printdiv(mydiv)
{
var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
var footstr = "</body>";
var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr+footstr;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
return false;
}

Comment: I want to print when click on a button

Comment: Okay got it.wait.

Comment: Hello please can you try this link and click on button shown like : "Print this page"
https://plnkr.co/edit/sQiJfyaZYbFtChXWAjRn?p=preview

Comment: We are using "rp3150 star" printer, I have tried with your code but still white space coming. Here is the screenshot http://prateekmobile.justevent.in/printpage.jpg

Comment: Hello @romil this is not coding issues, you have to solve it by setting into printer may be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I googled a bit and it seems to look like the browsers print-footer is the problem.

Maybe this helps:
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/page-size-when-printing-pos-receipts-5443

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, while previewing, you get margin default then we have to just margin none after that this is working fine